# How to import code style from java file to eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, coding-style

I have code style format XML file which is from IntelliJ IDEA, I tried to import in eclipse but didn't work, so I have code file which have all the java code like block, loops, condition, arrays, everything, so is there anyway to get code style from that java file to import in eclipse?

Thanks

Comment: If you asks for the proper nesting of all `blocks` , `loops` and statement. Just **Select All** and press `ctrl + i` indentation formatting will be done

Comment: no I'm not asking this, please read my post again, thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, the respective XML files are structured differently.